# GPU-parallelized function inside a structure using cuda

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda, gpu

I'm starting to use cuda, trying to improve the speed of my code.

So, I have a chain.h file where I define the Chain_1D structure and some functions

```
extern int      N;

struct Chain_1D
{
  int N_mons;

  double *x_old = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*N);

  float *X;

  // Allocate Unified Memory – accessible from CPU or GPU
  cudaMallocManaged(&X, N*sizeof(float));

  __global__ void step();
}; 

__global__
void Chain_1D::step()
{
  // Update x_old!
  for (int i = 0; i < N_mons; i++)    x_old[i] = X[i] ;

  int index = threadIdx.x;
  int stride = blockDim.x;


  for (int j=index ; j<N_mons ; j += stride)
  {
    if (j==0)
    {
        X[0] +=  - (x_old[2]-3*x_old[1]+2*x_old[0])*dt;
    }   else if (j==1)
    {
        X[1] +=  - (x_old[3]-4*x_old[2]+6*x_old[1]-3*x_old[0])*dt ;
    }   else if (j==N_mons-2)
    {
        X[N_mons-2] += -(x_old[N_mons-4]-4*x_old[N_mons-3]+6*x_old[N_mons-2]-3*x_old[N_mons-1])*dt;         
    }   else if (j==N_mons-1)
    {
        X[N_mons-1] += -(x_old[N_mons-3]-3*x_old[N_mons-2]+2*x_old[N_mons-1])*dt;           
    }   else
    {
        X[j] += - (x_old[j-2]+x_old[j+2]-4*x_old[j-1]-4*x_old[j+1]+6*x_old[j])*dt;
    }
  }
// Wait for GPU to finish before accessing on host
cudaDeviceSynchronize();     
}
```

Then I intend to use this in the `main()` function (and main.cu file)

```
Chain_1D chain;

chain.init_Chain();

for (int i = 1; i < N_runs; i++)
{
    chain.step<<<1, 200>>>();
}

cudaFree(chain.X);
```

It doesn't work, I believe it is due to the definition of this `__global__` function. Can anyone help?

Comment: Global functions and device  variable can't be members of classes or structures

Answer (score 1):

You should **move all required variables to the GPU** before executing a CUDA kernel that read them (e.g. like `N_mons` or `x_old`).

Moreover, I doubt your code compile due to the function call `cudaMallocManaged(&X, N*sizeof(float));` inside the `struct` declaration! It is neither valid in C++ nor in CUDA.

I advise you to read CUDA tutorials first (like this one: https://cuda-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: All this is true, but it isn't the root cause